# Does it make sense to choose UTF-32, based on concern that some basic rule will be broken for UTF-8?

Tags: c++, programming-practices, cross-platform, unicode

I'm working on an cross platform C++ project, which doesn't consider unicode, and need change to support unicode.

There is following two choices, and I need to decide which one to choose.

- Using UTF-8 (std::string) which will make it easy to support posix system.
- Using UTF-32 (std::wstring) which will make it easy to call windows API.

So for item #1 UTF8, the benefit is code change will not too many. But the concern is some basic rule will broken for UTF8, for example,

- string.size() will not equal the character length.
- search an '/' in path will be hard to implement (I'm not 100% sure).

So any more experience? And which one I should choose?

Comment: `wstring` is a `basic_string<wchar_t>`. `wchar_t` is implementation-defined in size and definitely not enough bits for UTF-32 on Windows.

Comment: Actually, searching for a "/" in UTF-8 is trivial. The guys who designed UTF-8 actually used their brains.

Comment: win32 API is not UTF-32, it's UTF-16. The width of wchar_t varies between platforms.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Use UTF-8.** `string.size()` won't equal the amount of *code points*, but that is mostly a useless metric anyway. In almost all cases, you should either worry about the number of *user-perceived* characters/glyphs (and for that, UTF-32 fails just as badly), or about the number of *bytes* of storage used (for this, UTF-32 is offers no advantage and uses more bytes to boot).

Searching for an ASCII character, such as `/`, will actually be *easier* than with other encodings, because you can simply use any byte/ASCII based search routine (even old C `strstr` if you have 0 terminators). UTF-8 is designed such that all ASCII characters use the same byte representation in UTF-8, and no non-ASCII character shares any byte with any ASCII character.

The Windows API uses UTF-*16*, and UTF-16 doesn't offer `string.size() == code_point_count` either. It also shares all downsides of UTF-32, more or less. Furthermore, making the application handle Unicode probably won't be as simple as making all strings UTF-{8,16,32}; *good* Unicode support can require some tricky logic like normalizing text, handling silly code points well (this can become a [security issue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDN_homograph_attack) for some applications), making string manipulations such as slicing and iteration work with glyphs or code points instead of bytes, etc.

There are more reasons to use UTF-8 (and reasons not to use UTF-{16,32}) than I can reasonably describe here. Please refer to the [UTF-8 manifesto](http://utf8everywhere.org/) if you need more convincing.

Comment: I am not really convinced. AFAIK - UTF32 encodes ALL code points into 4 bytes. As such ``utf32string.size() == number of characters`` (Please prove me wrong!). As such - from a coding and simplicity point of view, UTF32 is the ONLY encoding avoiding multi word handling complexity and as such allows for less complex and less error prone coding. Only a pity, that C++17 deprecates a lot of utf32 related stuff in ``<codecvt>, <locale>, ..." headers. And Win32 API does not have a MultiByteToUTF32() kind of function (only utf8->utf16).

Comment: @BitTickler While it's true that each codepoint can fit into a single char32_t, not all Unicode characters fit into a single codepoint.  For instance, if you want to type an emoticon with a different skin tone, you need two codepoints instead of just one.  So the following string of emojis is three characters encoded as 5 codepoints:  coded as (U+1F44B U+1F44B U+1F3FB U+1F44B U+1F3FF).  Some glyphs can be represented in multiple ways.  For instance, you can write ñ as two codepoints (U+006E U+0303) or as one codepoint (U+00F1).

Comment: @TomNorton Yes - as soon as people set out to make a 100% solution it turns ugly. And turns otherwise small projects into huge projects. (Imagine the author of the question starts to use ICU-TS libraries and the complexity of doing it right 100% increases the effort for his project by a factor 10...). So, in order to keep things sane, I am a proponent of "doing it well enough". In that spirit, it might be a good choice to say "I support UTF32 single code point only". And might get away with just a `using string32 = std::basic_string<char32_t>` and a few helper functions.